# Styling velocity markup with css in confluence 4.0

Tags: css, velocity, confluence

I have written a confluence macro. It uses velocity to generate html table. How can I style this markup with css if I don't use `<html>` and `<head>` tags in my velocity model. I have tried to do as in [this](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/CONFDEV/Including+Javascript+and+CSS+resources) example but id doesn't work(I mean it takes no effect and there is no css resource file that I have specified  inclusion on the code of result page of macro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand you correctly
you need to add links on your css files to *atlasian-plugin.xml*
 for example

```
<atlassian-plugin name='Just name' key='com.your.path.to.lib'
              plugins-version="2">
 <resource type="download" name="style.css" location="css/style.css">
        <property key="content-type" value="text/css"/>
    </resource>
</atlassian-plugin>
```

after that you need to add this link to the top of your velocity template

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="$req.contextPath/com.your.path.to.lib/style.css"
      type="text/css"/>
```

Comment: as I know tag <link> can be only in <head> tag, but I din't need to geberate tag <head>

Comment: not it's not necessarily here, i use it this way without adding into <head> and velocity template rendered good.